# How to pass a pre processor directive to a wrapped header file from Cython setup.py?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, distutils, preprocessor-directive

I've got a header file named `stb_image.h`, and it's wrapped in a `stb_image.pxd` file that only exposes the relevant functions that I need. `stb_image.h` can be found [here](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h). Below is my `stb_image.pxd` file.

```
cdef extern from "stb_image.h":
    ctypedef unsigned char stbi_uc
    stbi_uc *stbi_load(char *filename, int *x, int *y, int *comp, int req_comp)
    void stbi_image_free(void *retval_from_stbi_load)
```

I've only wrapped the functions I need. On `line 498` of `stb_image.h` there is a preprocessor directive:

```
#ifdef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
```

This directive wraps most of the implementation within the header file. Currently, everything works fine if I just `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` directly above that line, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this. Would I have to create a `setup.py` to do this?

Comment: You probably want to use a conditional statement: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#conditional-statements

Comment: For those curious, I made a setup.py and had an extension with this option: `define_macros=[("STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION", None)]`